# Rails slims template output in javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

As we know,we can output in slim like this:

```
div
  h1 =session[:mem]
```

But now,I have to output an var in javascript which embedded in slim.

For example:

```
javascript:
  var a=(=session[:mem]);
```

Obviously,this will raise an error.

So I wan to know how to output an var in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
javascript:
  var a=#{session[:mem]}; # or var a="#{session[:mem]}";
```